# What's difference between online/offline mounting/unmounting a disk?

Tags: diskpart

Can someone explain the difference between:

- online and mount
- offline and unmount

I know mount and unmount are not windows commands btw, I just wanna know the difference. Is mounting/dismounting a drive same as putting it into online/offline using DISKPART and why not if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, the drive being online or offline allows you to perform actions on the disk. Formatting, partitioning, etc.

Mounting it connects the drive to your filesystem so you can work on it like saving files. The drive is partitioned, it has a drive letter, it has a filesystem, etc.